# How to show missing data pattern with R script in Weka?

Tags: r, weka, missing-data

There has been a lot of filters in weka, but filters dealing with missing data is absent.

How can we use R to create such a filter or function for Weka to see missing data pattern?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open KnowledgeFlow, load nhanes.arff
2. link to RscriptExecutor, load the following script to it
3. link to TextViewer, and run

```r

```
library(VIM)   
library(mice)   
library(lattice)   
library(dplyr)

print('see missing pattern')   
print(md.pattern(rdata))
```

```